# fill Arry function not storing characters and outputting symbols

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote this program for class. I have a problem with displaying what in the arry 
all i get is symbols  instead of a character even though i filled them with char from a file provided by the professor. please help me figure out what is the problem here i need it for tomorrow

```
//  This program grades multiple choice exams1. Each exam consists of 20 questions. 
//Each question has one of four possible answers: A, B, C, or D.

#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

const int maxsize = 20;

int fillArry (FILE *fi,char arry[],const int maxsize);

double gradeExam (char arry[], char studarry[],const int maxsize);

void desplayResults (double right);

int main ()
{
    char arry[maxsize];
    char studarry[maxsize];
    int num,num1,i,right;
    FILE *fi,*sd;

    fi = fopen ("CorrectAnswers.txt","r");
    if ( fi == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Error opening input file.\n\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    sd = fopen ("StudentAnswers.txt", "r");
    if ( sd == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Error opening input file.\n\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    num = fillArry (fi,arry,maxsize);
    num1 = fillArry (sd,studarry,maxsize);
    for (i=0;i<maxsize;i++)
    {   
    printf("%c\n",arry);
    }

    for (i=0;i<maxsize;i++)
    {   
    printf("%c\n",studarry);
    }

    right = gradeExam (arry, studarry ,maxsize);
    printf("you got %i right\n", right);
    desplayResults (right);
    return 0;
}

int fillArry (FILE *fi,char arry[],const int maxsize)
{
    int u = 0;

    while((fscanf(fi,"%c",&arry)==1 )&& u< maxsize)

    {
        u++;    
    }


    return u;
}

double gradeExam (char arry[], char studarry[],const int maxsize)
{
    int i, right=0, wrong=0;

    for (i=1;i<=maxsize;i++)
    {
        if (arry[i]==studarry[i])
            right++;
        else
        {    
            printf ("question number %i :%c is wrong, the correct answer is %c\n\n",i,studarry,arry);
            wrong++;
        }

    }

    printf("\nnumber of wrong answers: %i\n",wrong);
    return right;   
}

void desplayResults (double right)
{
    double res;
    res = (right/20)*100;
    printf("You got %s %.2lf on the exam\n","%",res);
    if (res<70)
    printf ("You failed the exam\n");
    else
    printf ("You passed the exam\n");
}
```

Comment: why you are not closing the opened files?

Comment: Can you provide example of the input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your fscanf statement. Try this out.

fscanf(fi,"%s",arry)

Also, for displaying the array contents, you have to do it like this :

```
for(i=0; i<maxsize; i++)
{
     printf("%c",arry[i]);
}
```

**EDIT1** : I have verified the same thing at my end and it is working. Please check the contents of the file CorrectAnswers.txt.

**EDIT2** : I got the problem. It is in your print statement :

printf ("question number %i :%c is wrong, the correct answer is %c\n\n",i,studarry,arry);

Please correct it to :

printf ("question number %i :%c is wrong, the correct answer is %c\n\n",i,studarry[i],arry[i]);

Comment: All the calculation is right. however it still output symbols instead of the characters in the file this is how the file is organised.

Comment: A
D
B
C
A
A
D
B
D
C
A
D
B
A
C
C
D
B
C
A

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful now it is working perfectly.i had to change the why the data was organized in the file.i put them all in one line with no spaces,instead of one on each line.